# Needing the same ID for two different entries in one tablerow

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I built an app that solves a railway optimization problem. You can create some stations which you'll need to create a timetable with a trainnumber, arrival station, arrival time, departure station, departure time and the demand for this railconnection. Now i got the problem, that I have only one station_id which is used for the departure station but I need the station_id for my arrival station too. This is essential because when I delete a station I want that the correspondending railconnection using this station to be deleted too. Here is a little excerpt of my schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160310101628) do

create_table "stations", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "shortcut"
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
end

create_table "timetables", force: :cascade do |t|
t.integer  "train_number"
t.string   "departure_station"
t.string   "departure_time"
t.string   "arrival_station"
t.string   "arrival_time"
t.integer  "demand_first_class"
t.integer  "demand_second_class"
t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
t.integer  "station_id"
end

end
```

Is there a command that creates, when creating a new station, e.g. a station_departure_id that has allways the same id number as the station_id?
Are there other possibilities to solve this issue?

Comment: Posting the respective model[s] would make much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so if I have understood correctly:

You want each `Timetable` to have both a departure station and arrival station, and ensure that when a `Station` is deleted, that any corresponding `Timetable`s that have that `Station` as either departure or arrival station are also deleted.

You could achieve this with something along the lines of:

```ruby
class Timetable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :departure_station, class: 'Station', foreign_key: :departure_station_id
  belongs_to :arrival_station, class: 'Station', foreign_key: :arrival_station_id

  # ...
end
```

```ruby
class Station < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :departure_timetables, class: 'Timetable', foreign_key: :departure_station_id, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :arrival_timetables, class: 'Timetable', foreign_key: :arrival_station_id, dependent: :destroy

  #...
end
```

The `dependent: :destroy` option on the `has_many` associations in the `Station` class ensures that any `Timetable` that has that station as *either* departure station *or* arrival station will be deleted when that `Station` is deleted.

Comment: The solution is not working - I guess because I've no departure_station and arrival_station in my station table, respectively i've no seperated departure and arrival station table. The optimization problem is a circulation railway problem, so every station that is created must be at least one time a departure and at least one time an arrival station! That is why I built just one station table and one timetable station. I've updated my first post so you can see the two tables "stations" and "timetables" with its entries.I hope that I described the problem fairly understandable..